# I want to use this pattern to allow only these string like '#00000001'

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, regex, spring

**My code is**

```
let bikeno = $('input:text[name=bikeno]').val().trim();
let regBikeno = /^#\d{8}*$/;

if(!regBikeno.test(bikeno)) {
    alert("자전거 일련번호를 정확히 입력해 주세요.");
    return false;
}
```

I want to allow this pattern (#00000001).

The allowed string starts with `#` and consists of eight numbers.

Comment: Remove the `*` after the quantifier `^#\d{8}$`

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove the `*` to allow just 8 digits after the # :

```
let regBikeno = /^#\d{8}$/;
```

**SAMPLE:**

```js
$('#check').on('click', function() {
  let bikeno = $('input:text[name=bikeno]').val().trim();
  let regBikeno = /^#\d{8}$/;

  if (!regBikeno.test(bikeno)) {
    console.log("DOESN'T MATCH");
  } else {
    console.log("MATCH");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="bikeno" value="#33333333">

<button id="check">CHECK</button>
```

Comment: It's working!! Thanks!!